# XSLT: Remove namespace prefix from elements after first tag<POSLog> in a xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

we have a requirement to remove the prefix `<dsr:LineItemItems>6</dsr:LineItemItems>` in XML content, when we used the below code it was successfully removing the prefix "dsr" from xml elements but we need the xmlns namespaces in the output xml payload which is present in the POSLog tag.

Need all the namespaces/content present in the input first tag `<POSLog>` in the output xml too.

Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<POSLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dsr="http://www.dsr.com/rsd/tlog/markup/poslog" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd http://www.dsr.com/rsd/tlog/markup/poslog DSRPOSLog.xsd" xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/">
 <dsr:LineItemItems>6</dsr:LineItemItems>
```

XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dsr="http://www.dsr.com/rsd/tlog/markup/poslog" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd 
http://www.dsr.com/rsd/tlog/markup/poslog DSRPOSLog.xsd" xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
        <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output xml by the xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<POSLog schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd http://www.dsr.com/rsd/tlog/markup/poslog DSRPOSLog.xsd">
 <LineItemItems>6</LineItemItems>
```

Need the output as below with all the namespaces without change in the First Tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<POSLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dsr="http://www.dsr.com/rsd/tlog/markup/poslog" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd http://www.dsr.com/rsd/tlog/markup/poslog DSRPOSLog.xsd" xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/">
      <LineItemItems>6</LineItemItems>
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of creating an element in the result tree, and they differ in how they handle namespaces:

- `xsl:element` creates an element with no namespaces other than those used in the element name and in the names of its attributes
- `xsl:copy` copies all the namespaces present on the source element you are copying whether or not they are actually used
- a literal result element (e.g. `<POSLog>`) copies all the namespaces that are in scope for the element in the stylesheet, other than namespaces excluded using `exclude-result-prefixes`

So you want to create the outermost element of your result document using either `xsl:copy` or a literal result element, not using `xsl:element`.

The other problem you have is that you have renamed `xsi:schemaLocation` as schemaLocation. That happened because you used `<xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"/>`. It would be better here to simply use `xsl:copy-of` to copy the attribute.

Comment: The problem here seems to be with attributes, not elements.

Comment: Extended my answer to address the problem with schemaLocation, if that's what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra template to match the document element and copy it, rather than reconstructing a new element without namespaces. And in the existing template matching elements, add an attribute to indicate the namespace in the `xsl:element` constructor.

The following stylesheet ensures that all elements are bound to the namespace `http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/` and that the namespace prefix `dsr` is retained:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dsr="http://www.dsr.com/rsd/tlog/markup/poslog" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd 
    http://www.dsr.com/rsd/tlog/markup/poslog DSRPOSLog.xsd" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />

<!-- copy the document element, preserving it's namespaces -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

 <!--create elements using the local-name, but bound to the desired namespace -->   
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```